# If a function f(x) has a p-norm then does it automatically have a (p-1)-norm ? or a (<p)-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Hi Id like to know if a function has a p norm does that mean it automatically has a norm for al llower values of p ?. What about higher values ?.

I am trying to write a proof and would like to use this if provable.

Thanks

Comment: In other, perhaps simpler, words you question is this: Suppose that $p<q$, is it true that $\ell_p\subseteq\ell_q$?

Comment: I thought $l_p$ meant series and $L_p$ meant functions, but yes I supose that is what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't notice the "function" and immediately assume sequence (which is also a function). You might want to edit, then, and make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are counterexamples in each direction. Take $f(x)=x^{-a}$ and check for which values $p=p(a)$ $f(x)\in L^p$ on interval $(0,1]$ and for which $q=q(a)$ $f(x)\in L^q$ on interval $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: Answering yourself, eh? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If the support $A$ of your function has finite measure, then if $\displaystyle \int_A |f|^p\ d\mu$ exists, so does $\displaystyle \int_A \max(1, |f|^p)\ d\mu$ and thus $\displaystyle \int_A |f|^q\ d\mu$ for $1 \leq q \leq p$.

This does not hold if the support of the function has infinite measure, as can be seen by considering $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x\geq 1$ (which is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but is in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $p>1$).